# Using Dudley Integral to estimate maximum singular value of Gaussian random matrices

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, random-matrix

On Exercise 5.14 of [*Wainwright*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/highdimensional-statistics/8A91ECEEC38F46DAB53E9FF8757C7A4E), it provides a way to estimate maximum singular value of Gaussian random matrices using the one-step discretization bound and Gaussian comparison inequality as shown.
[image]

Can we use Dudley Integral to estimate it? Intuitively I thought it works but I didn't work it out since there are too few examples of [*Wainwright*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/highdimensional-statistics/8A91ECEEC38F46DAB53E9FF8757C7A4E) about Dudley Integral. It was hard for me to cap it.

Comment: See pages 122 and 125 of [*Probability in High Dimension* by van Handel](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~rvan/APC550.pdf).